# Why is pixel manipulation with pygame.surfarray slower than with pygame.image?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm writing an application that does a lot of per-pixel image manipulation.  These manipulations are sometimes done on every pixel in the image, and sometimes on just certain select pixel - drawing irregular shapes etc.

All my internet searching has insisted that manipulating individual pixels in pygame.Surface objects, using get_at() and set_at(), is very slow, and pygame.surfarray should be used instead, especially when working on all pixels in the image.  However, the time tests I have run show Surface objects to be nearly 10x faster in these operations.  Here is a simple test that iterates over each pixel in an image, halves the colour values, and saves the result in a new image:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame, time

imgPath="/home/jeremy/dev/warp/img/test/softRedDot.jpg"

img = pygame.image.load(imgPath)
sz = img.get_size()
ret = pygame.Surface(sz)

tStart = time.time()
for x in xrange(sz[0]):
    for y in xrange(sz[1]):
        clr = img.get_at((x, y))
        clr2 = (clr[0]*.5, clr[1]*.5, clr[2]*.5)
        ret.set_at((x, y), clr2)

tTotal = time.time() - tStart
print "tTotal image    ", tTotal


imgSA = pygame.surfarray.array3d(img)
ret = pygame.Surface(sz)
retSA = pygame.surfarray.array3d(ret)

tStart = time.time()
for x in xrange(sz[0]):
    for y in xrange(sz[1]):
        clr = imgSA[x][y]
        clr2 = (clr[0]*.5, clr[1]*.5, clr[2]*.5)
        retSA[x][y] = clr2

tTotal = time.time() - tStart
print "tTotal surfarray", tTotal
```

And here are some compiled times:

```
tTotal image     0.0175378322601
tTotal image     0.0251939296722
tTotal image     0.0280380249023
tTotal image     0.031506061554
tTotal image     0.0174198150635
tTotal image     0.0174269676208
tTotal image     0.0196499824524
tTotal surfarray 0.140149116516
tTotal surfarray 0.155483961105
tTotal surfarray 0.13768196106
tTotal surfarray 0.117908000946
tTotal surfarray 0.166879892349
tTotal surfarray 0.122611999512
tTotal surfarray 0.149390935898
```

Why is surfarray so much slower?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Further testing indicates that it's the surfarray querying that seems to be taking the bulk of the time, ie "clr = imgSA[x][y]".